# Pseudocode for finding the maximal coordinate in a set

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

The maximal points of a set are points that have x and y-coordinates which are greater than or equal to the x and y coordinates of every other point. I have a set whose points are sorted by increasing x-coordinates.

This needs to be done recursively/divide-and-conquer.

My approach was akin to: 
1. Go to the end of the array to find the coordinates with the largest x-coordinate 
2. Do a merge sort on the y-values of these x-coordinates
3. Go to the end of that sorted array, the largest y-values found here are the maximal points.

However, this would be O(n log n) due to the merge sort and I was told that it is possible to write code that runs in O(n). Can anyone provide recursive pseudocode which could do this in linear time?

Comment: Note: Sets are generally not considered orderable. This is about a sequence/collection, where the elements are guaranteed unique as a precondition.

Comment: I do not understand, what exactly must be greater? The sum of (x,y), euclidian distance sqrt(x^2 + y^2)?

Comment: Basically, just assume you have an array containing xy-coordinates and you are trying to find the greatest coordinates. i.e. The coordinates which has the largest x and y-value compared to all the others. Not the sum or distance, but straight up, the largest x and largest y.

Comment: I am fairly sure that "recursively/divide-and-conquer" is a misunderstanding on your part.  I also am sure that your definition of "maximal points" should be, "no point has a larger x and y coordinate".  My only remaining hint for your homework is "start with the largest x and work backwards."

Comment: So you are asking how to find a maximal element in an unsorted array in O(n). Are you sure you don't already know how to do this?

Comment: largest x and y? so what will be return if you have only two points (1,3) and (3,1) ? what should be the largest?